# Append data from one mysql server to another mysql server

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to append the data from one `MySQL` server A (outlet) to another `MySQL` server B (HQ) in different geographical locations. I want the outlet price information to be uploaded to HQ. I write a code but was stuck. I am not able to include the HQ connection.

The HQ server having the IP address of: 103.13.100.67.

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace PreparedStatement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = @"server=192.168.1.100;userid=Super;password=P@ssw0rd;database=test";

            using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES(@name, @price)";
        
            using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Proton2");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 666002);

            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("row inserted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @danny, I believe that the code you attached misses out the enclosing braces for `using` block for `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand`, please adding those braces, re-format code indent, and edit in your question. Thank you.

Comment: @YongShun The `using` seems [properly declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations) to me.

Comment: Hi @Llama, thanks for clarifying. First time know about it. So I withdraw my first comment? Thank you.

Comment: I had missed out the connection string for another mysql server in this C# program. Is anybody can help to provide the code. Thanks.